# fread or fwrite gives "Bad file number"

Tags: c, gcc, fwrite, fgets

I am using MinGW in Windows 8.1 and I have an input text file of raw numbers (one per line) and I want to write them as binary in a new binary file. The example is compiling without problems with:

```
gcc -pedantic -Os -c my_code.c -o my_code.exe
```

but the output is

```
$ my_code.exe
sh: ./my_code.exe: Bad file number
```

This is the code I wrote:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *prob;
    int length;
    char buffer[30];

   // Open file containing numbers
    if ((prob = fopen("raw_numbers.txt","r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open raw_numbers.txt\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Create output binary file */
    fp = fopen( "file.bin" , "w" );

    while( ! feof(prob) )
    {
        fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), prob);
        fwrite((const void*) & buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), fp);
    }

    fclose(prob);
    fclose(fp);
    return(0);
}
```

Using

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 3.4.4 (msys special)
```

Comment: I think you're supposed to pass `buffer`, instead of `&buffer` to fwrite.

Comment: Still the Bad file number persists without the &

Comment: You have to check if the file `file.bin` has been really opened.

Comment: [while(!feof(fp)) is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have multiple errors in your program:

- you should test for failure to create the output file.
- you should test the return value of `fgets()` instead of using `while (!feof())...`, which does not do what you think as explained in [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- you should pass `buffer` to `fwrite` instead of `&buffer`
- you should pass the number of bytes to write (`strlen(buffer)`) instead of the size of the buffer.
- you say the output file should be binary, but you open it as a text file and write text to it.  Did you mean to convert the numbers to binary and write the binary representation?

Here is an alternative that implements the above:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *prob;
    int value;
    char buffer[30];

    /* Open file containing numbers */
    if ((prob = fopen("raw_numbers.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open raw_numbers.txt: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Create output binary file */
    if ((fp = fopen("file.bin", "wb")) == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open file.bin: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), prob) != NULL) {
        value = atoi(buffer);
        if (fwrite(&value, sizeof(value), 1, fp) != 1) {
            printf("Error writing to file.bin: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    fclose(prob);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

The shell diagnostic is misleading, but here is what it means: the file `my_code.exe` has a signature (also known as magic number) that is not recognized as an executable file. The kernel cannot determine how to run the file from its magic number, hence *Bad file number*.

The reason is your compilation command: `gcc -pedantic -Os -c my_code.c -o my_code.exe` compiles the source file `my_code.c` to object format instead of linking directly to executable format. Remove the `-c` option to compile and link in one step:

```
gcc -pedantic -Os my_code.c -o my_code.exe
```

Comment: "Did you mean to convert the numbers to binary and write the binary representation?" Yes!! That's exactly what I want. But your code also is returning Bad file number on execution.

Comment: @Veronica: see my updated answer about the mysterious shell error message... this one was tricky!